# django 1.11 Template can't not load static file

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, django-templates

i set it up `STATICFILES_DIRS` `STATIC_URL` in settings.py

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'projectName', 'static'),
    ]
```

and i want to use javascript files in template but it is not working.
js file path is `app/static/app/new.js`
and i used it in template using this code

```
    {% load static %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "app/new.js" %}">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                alert(1);
                new_function();
            });
        </script>
```

function in new.js as well as alert does not working.
If I delete the src part in script tag, the alert works fine.
I can see the new.js script by accessing the path that appears in the chrome developer tool.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The behaviour of script elements with both `src` and content is not well defined. Why are you doing this?

Comment: About serving static files, you should to explain if you are in [develoment mode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) or in [production](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#deployment)

Comment: i don't know about that....

Comment: i cutted jquery part and pasted to new.js then it is working

Comment: I'm sorry I asked a stupid question.